# How to simulate HTTPS on a native application?

Tags: javascript, html, https, native, qr-code

I am using [Instascan](https://github.com/schmich/instascan) library which allows me to access camera on both desktop and mobile devices. However, when I convert the website to a native Android or Iphone app I cannot access the camera. The documentation of Instascan library says

> Chrome requires HTTPS when using the WebRTC API. Any pages using this
>   library should be served over HTTPS

Is there a way to trick a native application to think that it is being served over HTTPS?

Comment: What's kind of framework are you converting this to native app?

Comment: Its a wordpress website. I am using gonative.io website to do the conversion

Comment: You have to ask gonative.io staffs how to simulate with HTTPS, otherwise is not possible.